# Which exact dependencies are provided by the cluster manager at runtime?

Tags: apache-spark

The official ["Submitting Applications" documentation guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#bundling-your-applications-dependencies) contains the following line under "Bundling Your Application’s Dependencies"

> When creating assembly jars, list Spark and Hadoop as provided dependencies; these need not be bundled since they are provided by the cluster manager at runtime.

I have a few questions about what exactly this means. They all seem related enough to be put int the same SO question, but I can break it up if that makes accepting multiple answers for different parts easier.

**Which spark jars are provided?** Spark is made up of multiple artifacts. For example `spark-core`, `spark-sql`, and `spark-mllib`. Are all of these provided by the cluster manager? Does it depend on how to you start your cluster?

**What if one of our application deps is a transient dep of a Spark jar?** In my case, I depend on `scala-library`, `scala-reflect`, and a few other deps which are transient deps of Spark. If Spark is provided, we should be able to assume that these deps are provided as well... but should they be scoped as such so that they are not included in the uber jar?

**What happens when we include a jar in the uber-jar that Spark provides?** One obvious consequence is that the jar file size will be bigger than it needs to be. Assuming the jar includes the same version, I wouldn't expect to get any `NoSuchMethodError` or similar classpath issues. Is that correct? What if the jar contains a different version than what Spark provides? Will the cluster deterministically give one version preference? Or will there be 2 versions on the classpath and potential for the usual mismatched version errors?

**Is there any way to control which jars are provided by the cluster manager?** It seems to me that one way to reduce this issue is have the cluster provide as little as possible and allow for each application to provide more deps in the jar. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't think the JVM tag makes sense on this question, since it's all about Spark and not a specific JVM behavior.

Comment: Fair enough. I thought it might be relevant because some of these questions overlap with the specific semantics of the "provided" scope, as mentioned in the Spark docs. I'll remove the tags if you think that was a mistake on my part.

Comment: I'm watching the JVM tag (as are many others), looking for questions that are really about the JVM itself, and not software that merely runs on it. That's why I'm here. I don't understand Spark.

Comment: Perhaps I am not thinking correctly about what the community considers "the JVM itself". The topic is largely about how to properly control the classpath when certain deps are provided. That said, my phrasing of the question is specifically in terms of how Spark handles these issues so I see your point and will remove the tag. Thanks.